# Finding Apex Application Tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to get a list of all the navigation menu used in my Apex Application using SQL query.

For example, I could get my Application pages when used this query

select  `select * from apex_application_pages where application_id =25459;`

I would like to get all my navigation menu lists
anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this sql query
`select * from APEX_APPLICATION_LIST_ENTRIES where APPLICATION_ID = :APP_ID AND LIST_NAME = 'Navigation Menu'`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is not recommended to modify or perform CRUD operations on internal Apex table, what you are looking for the table called `WWV_FLOW_LIST_TEMPLATES` and for the entries in a list `WWV_FLOW_LIST_ITEMS` table.

Those tables are stored under the APEX schema that is dependant on your APEX version. For example for my version, the schema is APEX_230100 so I can run sql queries as:
`select * from APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_LIST_ITEMS;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the APEX_DICTIONARY view when looking for the relevant dictionary view that will contain your application meta-data
eg:

```
select apex_view_name 
from apex_dictionary 
where apex_view_name like '%LIST%' 
and column_id = 0;

APEX_VIEW_NAME                  
--------------------------------
APEX_APPLICATION_LISTS
APEX_APPLICATION_LIST_ENTRIES
APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_LIST
```

This view also contains a comments column, absent from these results for brevity.

I've restricted to column_id = 0 to limit only to view names, as opposed to including all their column names.

You can also view this information in the Application Builder -> Workspace Utilities -> APEX Views.
[image: application builder views]